# Sequence generation based on a condition in informatica powercenter

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

I need to create a sequence based on the data in a column, the sample table is as follows:
[image]

The sequence to be provided is like, if group = bfd then new_id = id + sequence in <0-200> if group = klm or kln then new_id = id + sequence in <201-499>

The output should be something like:

[image]

I tried using 2 Sequence generators, first starts from 0 and increment by 1.
second starts from 200 and increment by 1, Then using IIF in expression transformation
seq_1 = attach NEXTVAL from sequence generator 1
seq_2 = attach NEXTVAL from sequence generator 2

new_id = TO_INTEGER ( IIF( group ='bfd', id || seq_1,
IIF( group = 'klm' or group ='kln', id || seq_2)
)
)

But the above logic gives output as follows..

[image]

The sequence needs to be generated only for the mentioned group..

Is there a way I could achieve this in informatica.. using a UDF or modifying any of my existing logic

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior of seq gen. You need to use sorter and expression transformation to do this.

1. Use sorter to sort data on `group`.
2. Use expression transformation. Create ports like below. io = input/output port, v - variable port, o- output only port.

```
io_id=id
io_group=group
v_prev_seq1= IIF( io_group ='bfd', IIF(isnull (v_seq1),-1, v_seq1))
v_prev_seq2= IIF( io_group ='klm' or group ='kln', IIF(isnull (v_seq2),199, v_seq2))
v_seq1= IIF(NOT ISNULL(v_prev_seq1),v_prev_seq1+1,0)
v_seq2=IIF(NOT ISNULL(v_prev_seq2),v_prev_seq2+1,200)
o_new_id = 
IIF( io_group ='bfd', id || v_seq1, IIF( group = 'klm' or group ='kln', id || v_seq2))
```

Link io_id,io_group,o_new_id to your target.
Explanation -
v_prev_seq1 - in case of bfd, this will be -1 in the beginning. Then when, first row comes, v_seq1 value will be 0. Then for next bfd, it will increase by 1. for non bfd groups this will not increase or be null.
Similarly v_prev_seq2 and v_seq2 will increase only if group is kln or klm.

Pls note, your expected output has an underscore `_` in new_id column but in your code its absent. I ignored this as well - pls add if needed.

Comment: I tried the above solution... This can be the potential solution but for the other group the sequence is not starting from 200 .. the output is as below..

id | group | new_id 
101| bfd | 101_1 
123| bfd | 123_2 
102| klm | 102_2 
693| klm | 693_3 
563| kln | 563_4

I tried with more data... The sequence for KLM and KLN starts from 2 for some reason!

Comment: could you please run session in verbose mode with 10 records and attach the session log or examine where is it not working?

Comment: Yes sure, will try to figure out from log.. I will attach it here..Thanks for the help!